# Return values to pointers initialized in function

Tags: c

Starting to re-learn C after many, many years, and I'm a little confused why something I'm doing is working:

```
char *test_foo() {
    char *foo = "foo";
    return foo;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *foo = test_foo();
    printf(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Maybe I'm misunderstanding my book, but I'm under the impression that the character pointer initialized in the `test_foo` function should have its memory block released after the function returns, which should make my `printf` not print out "foo" like it does in this example.

Is this just a case of the kernel not releasing this memory in time, or am I misunderstanding why this happens?

Comment: In C, strings enclosed in double closed are statically allocated in the executable itself by your compiler/linker, so the memory is always available. This is why they're typically immutable and writing to them is undefined behavior that typically results in a crash. Had you done `char foo[] = "foo"`, you'd be right - that would return a locally allocated (on the stack) array.

Comment: This makes it much more clear, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, a string literal is an anonymous array of constant characters with static storage duration. The memory for a string literal is not released when the surrounding function returns. The memory for the pointer `foo` is, but its value is copied to the caller before it's released. What you are doing is perfectly well defined and sane.

Comment: Is this an implementation detail or is it guaranteed by the standard?

Comment: Nevermind, I've found the answer. Everything is fine.

Comment: This makes a ton of sense.  Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 4):

you end up returning a pointer to a literal ("foo")

your code is the same as

```
char *test_foo() {
    return "foo";
}
```

Note however that you make a bad assumption. You assumed that because your code printed "foo" that everything you did was good (in this case it is), but even in a 'bad' example your code many times would succeed in a simple test but explode in a more real-world example.

To see the case you are expecting try

```
   char *test_foo() {
     char foo[10];
     strcpy(foo,"foo")
        return foo;
    }
```

now your string is on the stack and will be released at function exit

Comment: Upvoted for mentioning that UB will often appear to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it works, is because `foo()` returns a pointer to initialised data -  a string literal. That string data is not on the local stack, so the pointer that `foo()` returns is good.